# Do I need to deallocate a pointer to a function?

Tags: c++, c

For some code I'm writing, I have a function pointer. I use it for some time, but I don't know whether I need to explicitly deallocate the pointer. Here is a simplified version of my code

```
struct Person
{
    void (*action) ();
}

void action()
{
    printf("Action has been called\n");
}

int main()
{
    Person p;
    p->action = &action;

    // My question is whether or not I need to do this
    // free (p->action);
    // p->action = NULL;
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: Did you say `malloc`?

Comment: Did you allocate space for the function? What do you understand that is a pointer?

Comment: You deallocate things, not pointers to things. Do you want to deallocate the function?

Comment: `p->action` should be `p.action` instead.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I have a function pointer. I use it for some time, but I don't know whether I need to explicitly deallocate the pointer.

**No.** You don't need to deallocate anything using `free()`, you never had dynamically allocated with `malloc()` or alike.

---

In fact it would be practically impossible to create a function pointer using `malloc()`.

Comment: `malloc()` can be used to allocate a memory block that is then populated with CPU instructions and executed via a function pointer. In that scenario, you would need to `free()` the memory when done using it.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Sure, I know. That's why I said _practically impossible_. What you're claiming requires weird hacks.

Comment: Thanks. That's what I thought and I wanted to be sure since I'm making a fairly large program with tons of these around.

Answer (score 2):

> I don't know whether I need to explicitly deallocate the pointer.

Your `action` variable is just a pointer.  You don't free a pointer itself, you free what it is pointing at.  But since are not allocating memory for the function being pointed at, you are not responsible for freeing it.